# Why inheritance in Activities makes activity function not work

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have 2 activity classes, one being abstract that offers a kind of framework to the other classes that will have similar behavior. So lets say activity ActA is parent offering the framework and activity ActB is the child.

I have the framework activity like the following:

```
public class ActA extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        // do stuff for setting up framework
    }
}
```

Then I have a child activity like so:

```
public class ActB extends ActA{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

The code commented like `do other stuff` is not actually called. 
What is the problem as to me it looks legit?

Comment: How do you launch `ActB`?

Comment: Did you declare ActB in manifest.xml?

Comment: You should explain what does "not work" mean

Comment: @SamuelEminet Good point. Just like I launch any other activity. `Intent i = new Intent(this,ActB.class);
startActivity(i);`

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode I did. But I didn't declare ActA. But the same happens if I do. I think if I don't declare then it would just crash, not refuse to run the code

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I have explained that if you read the body of the question rather than jut title. Not work means the code in the child activity doesn't run. Just the parent's code does.

Comment: Then I can carefully assume that the key is the matching between Bundle and Activity( Context).

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode I'm sorry I don't understand the key. You mean the android:name? If so then yes.

Comment: @anon I meant that I thought that if we call OnCreate Method of ActA with the same bundle from inherited (ActB) then  it may cause a problem because the bundle of ActB may not be compatiblewith ActA.

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode that is what is happening as far as I can tell. Since I'm calling `super.onCreate(b)` from ActB then definitely bundle of ActB is going to ActA. But in a cold run scenario bundle will be null so that shouldn't be a problem. Also by debugging I see that when ActA onCreate runs smoothly and finishes running, but the rest of ActB onCreate after `super.onCreate(b)` doesn't run.

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode its very weird. I made sure ActA calls super.onCreate(null) and now ActB's onCreate code is running. I don't have any clue what happened. I'd like an explanation if anyone knows the issue but for this question I will accept your answer it was constructive and useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it another way like

```
 public abstract class ActA extends Activity{
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
          super.onCreate(b);
          // do stuff for setting up framework
         callForStuff();
      }


 protected abstract void callForStuff();

}
```

Then you need not call onCreate() method again.Only you have to do it like

```
 public class ActB extends ActA{

    @Override
    protected void callForStuff(){
      // abstract method
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you;

Comment: I know that way and that is what I am doing. My question is why the inheritance doesn't make code in ActB work, that workaround seems too dirty

Comment: Shouldn't "protected abstract void callForStuff();" be between the brackets?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode which brackets?

Comment: public abstract class ActA extends Activity{ @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle b){ super.onCreate(b); // do stuff for setting up framework callForStuff(); }
protected abstract void callForStuff(); }

Comment: Inside the class, isn't it?